# TRANCOUNT mismatch

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This is the the sample stored procedure that I am using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateCustomer]
        @firstName nvarchar(50) = null,
        @lastName nvarchar(50) = null,
        @emailAddress nvarchar(50),
        @contactNumber varchar(15) =null,
        @street1 nvarchar(50) = null,
        @street2 nvarchar(50) = null,
        @city nvarchar(50) = null,
        @State nvarchar(50)= null,
        @Country nvarchar(50)=null,
        @postalCode varchar(5) = null,
        @middleName nvarchar(50),
        @password nvarchar(50),
        @membershipExpieryDate datetime,
        @status int OUT

    AS
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            SAVE TRANSACTION initialP
                DECLARE @lastAccessed datetime = GETDATE()
                DEClARE @uniqueCustomerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER= NEWID()
                BEGIN TRANSACTION
                    INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, LastAccessed, ContactNumber, 
                        Street1, Street2, City, State, Country, PostalCode, MiddleName, Password, MembershipExpieryDate)
                        VALUES(@uniqueCustomerID,@firstName, @lastName, @emailAddress, @lastAccessed, @contactNumber, @street1, @street2,
                         @city, @State, @Country, @postalCode, @middleName, @password, @membershipExpieryDate)



     INSERT INTO Roles(CustomersCustomerID,Role) VALUES(@uniqueCustomerID,'V') 
            COMMIT

            SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, LastAccessed, ContactNumber, 
                Street1, Street2, City, State, Country, PostalCode, MiddleName, MembershipExpieryDate FROM Customers WHERE EmailAddress = @emailAddress  

        SET @status =1
        COMMIT
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION initialP
        END
        SET @status =2
    END CATCH
```

And this is the code that I am using to get the query data:

```
ObjectParameter status = new ObjectParameter("status", typeof(int));
var dataSet = Entity.CreateCustomer(newCustomer.FirstName, newCustomer.LastName,
newCustomer.EmailAddress, newCustomer.ContactNumber, newCustomer.Street1, newCustomer.Street2,
newCustomer.City, newCustomer.State, newCustomer.Country, newCustomer.PostalCode, newCustomer.MiddleName,
newCustomer.Password, newCustomer.MembershipExpieryDate, status);
```

But when execiting this stored procedure it gives an error saying that Trans count missmatch.
As I know the `trans count` is incrimented by one when a `begin transaction` occurs.and decriment by one when an `commit` occures.
I have already map the function in the **function import** as it can return a complex type.

I can not understand the problem in this. To me it seems Ok. I want to know weather I am doing this correct or not with some detais. Thanks.

Edited:
This I what I found out by writing a sample code. I first thought it was with begin trans action and commit. But it is not. **It allows to select the values that are been inserted even before the commit statement** (Correct me if I am wrong.).
I created a Test Table which has 3 columns(test1 unique identifier, test2 int , test3 int) 
and I created a stored procedure call Test:
Its given below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestForCommit

    (
    @test11 int,
    @test111 int,
    @status int OUTPUT
    )

AS
    begin try
        declare @test1 uniqueidentifier  = NEWID()
        begin transaction
            insert into TestT1(Test1, Test11, Test111) values(@test1, @test11, @test111)
        commit
        select Test1, Test11, Test111 from TestT1 where Test1 = @test1
        SET @status = 1
    end try
    begin catch
        Rollback Transaction
        set @status =2
    end catch
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    RETURN
```

I have created a functional import in the in the entity model and I used it like this:

```
            ObjectParameter status = new ObjectParameter("status", typeof(int));
            SchoolEntities test = new SchoolEntities();
            var dataSet = test.TestForCommit(1, 1, status);
                //A:
                //(XXXXXXXXXXXXX)Console.WriteLine((int)status.Value);
                foreach (var item in dataSet)
                {
                    TestForCommit_Result t = item;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1} , {2}", t.Test1, t.Test11, t.Test111);

                }
                //B:
                Console.WriteLine((int)status.Value);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

***This //A: part is causing the problem. This gives a null reference exception. but  //B: part is working and giving the status value. I am still in search of why is it working like that. Thanks!!***

Comment: You are rolling back in case of an error, but outer transaction (first begin transaction in script) remains active. `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint_name does not decrement @@TRANCOUNT` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299)

Comment: So should I make it just a pair of 'begin translation' and 'commit'

Comment: Absolutely. You don't need to nest transactions to insert two records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Suggestion. (Set Xact_Abort On)

```
Begin Try
    Set NoCount On
    Set Xact_Abort On
    Begin Tran
        --Your Query
    Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateCustomer]
    @firstName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @lastName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @emailAddress nvarchar(50),
    @contactNumber varchar(15) =null,
    @street1 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @street2 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @city nvarchar(50) = null,
    @State nvarchar(50)= null,
    @Country nvarchar(50)=null,
    @postalCode varchar(5) = null,
    @middleName nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @membershipExpieryDate datetime,
    @status int OUT

AS
BEGIN TRY
    Set NoCount ON
    Set XAct_Abort ON
    DECLARE @lastAccessed datetime = GETDATE()
    DEClARE @uniqueCustomerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER= NEWID()

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, LastAccessed, ContactNumber, 
    Street1, Street2, City, State, Country, PostalCode, MiddleName, Password, MembershipExpieryDate)
    VALUES(@uniqueCustomerID,@firstName, @lastName, @emailAddress, @lastAccessed, @contactNumber, @street1, @street2,
    @city, @State, @Country, @postalCode, @middleName, @password, @membershipExpieryDate)

    INSERT INTO Roles(CustomersCustomerID,Role) VALUES(@uniqueCustomerID,'V') 
    COMMIT

    SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, LastAccessed, ContactNumber, 
    Street1, Street2, City, State, Country, PostalCode, MiddleName, MembershipExpieryDate FROM Customers WHERE EmailAddress = @emailAddress  

    SET @status =1
    COMMIT Tran
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SET @status =2
END CATCH
```

Comment: I removed my nested tran and commit, But I did not do was, I did not remove set status, because I want it out for further reference in the code.

Comment: Did you remove `IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)` etc from your `Catch block` ?

Comment: yes I removed it, but when I remove the set @status and I also changed the code to get the complex type. because statues return as a NULL. I want to get that value too if any error occurs I have give feedback to the user in my program.

Comment: All these days the code has been working. Thanks a lot RGI. But sorry to mention the problem is with the coding. I am editing it on the question itself. Thanks again. Sorry for the less activity due a illness :(

Comment: Yes, This code works fine. Thanks. Did you see my edit. RGI you are the best . Thanks a lot!! But by this I can not get the status value in the first place as I have mentioned in the edited question, I can get the status value only after I get the data set from the stored procedure. Now I have used this code to get my work done. But I am curious about the current issue. Thank you very much for the support  you have shown. Cheers!!